# There is a Sequence associated with the table. When i reset this sequence and inserting a data into a table data is not coming in ordered fashion

Tags: sql-server, sequence

there is a Sequence associated with the table. When i reset this sequence and inserting a data into a table data is not coming in ordered fashion.
Please Do suggest what should I do for the same

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: data will come ordered according to primary key of the table.

Comment: @Priyanka just cast the column as bigint in order by clause

Comment: @Iceman... Sorry...this is quite uncommon problem i thought if any one have idea about it
anyways I am using SQL server.

Comment: @Ravi.. Thank you..
now It is working as expected.
I changed datatype of the column where Sequence is kept to Bigint from nvarchar

Comment: Oracle, MySql AND Sql Server - aw, c'mon - please do NOT abuse tags. Use the tag that is pertinent to your RDBMS ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to guarantee ordering of a `SELECT` statement result set is by specifying an `ORDER BY` clause. This is regardless of the primary key and indexes as well as the order rows are inserted. If results are returned in the desired sequence without `ORDER BY`, it is by happenstance. See [ORDER BY is Required](http://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/) for a demo of this behavior.

That being said, if SQL Server chooses to use a traditional b-tree index in a trivial query without parallelism in the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, the storage engine will likely follow the forward page pointers and row offset array, resulting in a result ordered by the chosen index even without an `ORDER BY` clause. However, the same query may return results in a different order due to parallelism or if the storage engine uses an allocation order scan (e.g. in the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level). I would expect other ANSI-SQL compliant DBMS products to similarly require `ORDER BY`.

With the `ORDER BY` clause, the semantics of data type comparison will dictate the ordering of results.  Integer/numeric data types are ordered differently then character data.

Comment: I used order by also But still same result.
when i changed data type varchar to bigint i am getting expected result.